# Parameters name,surname,date of birth,birthplace,ID

Tags: null, default

In report builder i have set default null and allow null but when i run the report in firefox or internet explorer null is not set as default. It’s not already checked in the parameters, i need to check them one by one. Please help

```
Select* from patient where
     name = isnull(@name,name)
     and surname = isnull(@surname,surname)
     and birthplace = isnull (@birthplace,birthplace) 
     and ID = isnull (@ID,ID) 
     and dateofbirth = isnull (@DOB,dateofbirth)
```

Comment: Select* from patient where name = isnull(@name,name) and surname = isnull(@surname,surname) and birthplace = isnull (@birthplace,birthplace) and ID = isnull (@ID,ID) and dateofbirth = isnull (@DOB,dateofbirth) . I need to filter sometimes the name alone or birthofplace or surname etc.

Comment: Please be more clear when asking a question. You don't mention what kind of `report builder` you are talking about so it's quite impossible to help you at the moment. Also, please use better tags. I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Comment: I’m using reportbuilder 3.0. I need a query of patient with 5 parameters name,surname,dateofbirth,birthplace,ID. Also for example when i type name in the filter ssrs i should get data without filling the other filters such as surname,birthplace,ID etc. They should be set as default to null